# Recognize DateTime String as valid when containing day names in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek, tryparse

When a date string has the day of the week attached to it, TryParse fails:

```
DateTime d;
string dateString = "Tuesday May 1, 2012 9:00 AM";
return DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out d); // returns false
```

What is the best way to deal with this so that I can safely determine it IS a date, and furthermore convert it to such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell TryParseExact what format to look for:

```
DateTime d;
string dateString = "Tuesday May 1, 2012 9:00 AM";
return DateTime.TryParseExact(
   dateString,
   "dddd MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt",
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
   out d
);
```

Comment: So if there are a number of possible date formats, I have to TryParseExact each one?

Comment: There's another overload that allows you to specify an array of possible formats and it will try all of them until one works.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :)

```
        // Parse date and time with custom specifier.
        string dateValue = "Tuesday May 1, 2012 9:00 AM";
        string pattern = "dddd MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt";

        DateTime parsedDate;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.",
                              dateValue, parsedDate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.",
                              dateValue);
```

Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx